# Android - EditText issue with Listview

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext

I am creating a mobile application where Edit Text keeps on adding into the ListView. It works fine until the list view reaches the screen size later the edit text appending happens at the top in the case of simulator(nexus 6) whereas in mobile editText is not getting appended on reaching the screen size.

Can anyone help with the issue ?

Git hub link: 
https://github.com/Sudan1993/Bull-Cows-Android

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    public ArrayList<String> myItems = new ArrayList();

    public CustomAdapter() {
        //System.out.println("inside constructor default ::::::::");
        myItems.add("");
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return myItems.size();
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view,parent,false);

            //get the go button id and disable it
            goButton = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.go_button);
            goButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            final EditText editText = 
                   EditText)convertView.findViewById(R.id.editText);

            editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
                public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                    System.out.println("hasFocus ::: " + hasFocus+"");
                }
            });

            editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                }

                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                              int count, int after) {
                }

                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                          int before, int count) {
                    goButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    if(s.length()!=0) {
                        prevSeq = s.subSequence(0, s.length() - 1);
                        c = s.charAt(s.length()-1);
                    }
                    System.out.println("prev string ::: " + prevSeq );
                    System.out.println("entered string ::: " + s );
                    //eliminate duplicates
                    check = false;
                    if(prevSeq!=null) {
                        for (char m : prevSeq.toString().toCharArray()) {
                            if (m == c) {
                                editText.setError("Duplicate");
                                check = true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if(s.length() == 4 && !check) {
                        goButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                }
            });

            //get the id of bulls and cows
            final TextView bullText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.bulls);
            final TextView cowText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cows);

            goButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    bulls = cows = 0;
                    // Perform action on click
                    String strEntered = editText.getText().toString();
                    System.out.println(strEntered);
                    System.out.println(ltrToFind);
                    //different position increment the value of cows
                    for (int i = 0; i < ltrToFind.length(); i++)
                        for (int j = 0; j < strEntered.length(); j++)
                            if (ltrToFind.charAt(i) == strEntered.charAt(j) && i != j)
                                cows++;
                    //same position increment the value of bulls
                    for (int i = 0; i < ltrToFind.length(); i++)
                        if (ltrToFind.charAt(i) == strEntered.charAt(i))
                            bulls++;

                    System.out.println("bull and cow values ::: " + bulls + "\n" + cows);
                    //pass the values to next fragment if both bull and cow are zero
                    //if (mListener != null) {
                    if(bulls == 0 && cows == 0)
                        mListener.onFragmentInteraction(strEntered);

                    //}

                    bullText.setText(bulls + "");
                    cowText.setText(cows + "");

                    //disabling everything and adding a new row
                    goButton.setEnabled(false);
                    editText.setEnabled(false);
                    bullText.setEnabled(false);
                    cowText.setEnabled(false);

                    myItems.add("");
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });

        }
        return convertView;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
}
```

Fragment_one.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/layout_id">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Words"
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:height="@dimen/abc_action_bar_stacked_max_height"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="88dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="88dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Bulls"
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:height="@dimen/abc_action_bar_stacked_max_height"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_marginRight="26dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="26dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Cows"
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:height="@dimen/abc_action_bar_stacked_max_height"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="21dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="21dp" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/customlist"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"
     />

</RelativeLayout>
```

List_item.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 >

 <EditText
android:layout_width="150dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:hint="Type"
android:ems="10"
android:id="@+id/editText"
android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
android:layout_marginLeft="47dp"
android:layout_marginStart="47dp"
android:textSize="40dp"
android:textAlignment="center"
android:maxLength="4"
android:editable="true"
android:enabled="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
android:focusable="true"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:inputType="textFilter"/>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/go_button"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
    android:src="@drawable/go_button"
    android:background="@drawable/go_button"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/bulls"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:layout_marginRight="13dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="13dp"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/cows"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/cows"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/cows" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/cows"
    android:layout_marginRight="44dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="44dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: put the edittext code, where you are calling adapter notify.

Comment: Hi @Ritesh the entire getView code is there above... I didn't get which one you are asking.